# Run python program on startup in background on Intel Galileo

Tags: python, linux, startup, intel-galileo

I have a python program that is an infinity loop and send some data to my database.

I want this python script to run when I power my Intel Galileo. I tried to make a sh script `python myprogram.py` and made it run on startup in etc/init.d. When I restarted my Galileo, nothing happened-Linux didn't load, Arduino sketch didn't load and even my computer didn't recognize it.

I guess this happened because the python program was an infinity loop. 
Is there a way that I can run my system without problems and run my python script on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the `myprogram.py` run in background with `python myprogram.py &` and it worked. The `&` is used to run whatever process you want in background.